# Value of HiddenField to be the Text of DropDownList C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, hiddenfield

Using C# I need the value in the Hiddenfield below, which is currently "test" to be the 'Text' of the DropDownList. Any Ideas?

```
HiddenField hiddenField = new HiddenField { ID = "ValueHiddenField", Value = "test" };
```

.cs page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HiddenField hiddenField = new HiddenField { ID = "ValueHiddenField", Value = "test" };
        theForm.Controls.Add(hiddenField);
        string script = @"function updateCallBackReason() {
                callBackReason = document.getElementById('<%=ValueHiddenField.ClientID %>').value;
                return callBackReason;
            }";
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "callBackReasonScript", script, true);
```

.aspx

```
<asp:label runat="server" ID="lblCallbackReason" AssociatedControlID="dropCallbackReason" CssClass="textLabel">Reason for callback:</asp:label>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropCallbackReason" onChange="updateCallBackReason" ClientIDMode="Static" >
                <asp:ListItem Text="-- Select Reason --" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Booking a Test Drive" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Discussing a Purchase" Value="11"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Contract Hire Quotation" Value="45"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your function `updateCallBackReason` is not doing what is supposed to do (update hidden field value). If didn't get wrong your question, this is what you have to do.

```
string script = string.Format(@"function updateCallBackReason() {{
    var ddl = document.getElementById('dropCallbackReason');
    var callBackReason = document.getElementById('{0}');
    callBackReason.value = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
}}", hiddenField.ClientID );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, hopefully I'm not dense. But the 'ValueHiddenField.ClientID' at the end, returns doesn't exists in the current context.

Comment: Hi @Claudio-Redi - this returns - System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @wilsonlego: needed to escape `{` and `}` by `{{` and `}}`. Fixed that

Comment: Thanks for the amend @Claudio-Redi. When my script loads. In the console it writes 'callBackReason is not defined' & TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null when I try and run the updareCallBackReason on the console. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After binding your drop down to a data source, set the selected value of the drop down to the index of the text in the hidden field.

```
dropCallbackReason.SelectedIndex = dropCallbackReason.Items.IndexOf(dropCallbackReason.Items.FindByText(ValueHiddenField.Value.ToString()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, and thanks for the edit @Esoteric Screen Name, where abouts would I implement the code mentioned above?

Comment: @wilsonlego: It should be after the control (hidden field and drop down) are loaded. Try the Page PreRender event.